# Propagate event from deeply nested Child Component to Top Level component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following is my component tree.

```
DashboardComponent
  TaskManagementView
    TaskManagementForm
      SubmitButtonComponent
```

I need to pass the button clicked event from `SubmitButtonComponent` to the `DashboardComponent`.

One way of doing this would be as follows

```
<DashboardComponenet AddTask={AddSomeTask}>
  ....
  <TaskMangementView submitClicked={props.AddTask}>
    ....
    <TaskManagementForm ButtonClick={props.submitClicked}/>
      .....
      <SubmitButtonComponent onclick={props.ButtonClick}/>
      ....
    <TaskManagementForm />
    ....
  </TaskManagementView >
  ....
</DashboardComponent>
```

Is there some good way of passing the onClick to the DashboardComponent ? This is hard to maintain.

Comment: I'd suggest that passing the function down as a prop is the most suitable method to achieve your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

As Gaurav said, you can either pass the function down through the components as props. But this can get messy when there are many components in the middle

OR

I would recommend using something like [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) which will allow you to skip components in the middle and just access the function where needed.

Comment: Do you see Redux would help in this problem ?